# dql select return empty result symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, dql, empty-list, symfony3.x

I'm trying to get all videos from a DB that contain a keyword, It's an API REST building with Symfony 3. Here is a sample of the URL

```
http://localhost/Server/symfony/web/app_dev.php/video/search/prueba
```

Where "prueba" is the keyword that i'm trying to find

Here is the function..

```
public function searchAction(Request $request, $search = null){
    $helper = $this->get("app.helper");
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if($search != null){
        $dql = "SELECT v.title FROM BackendBundle:Video v "
                . "WHERE v.title LIKE :search OR "
                . "v.description LIKE :search ORDER BY v.id DESC";

        $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
                ->setParameter("search", "%search%");
    } else {
        $dql = "SELECT v FROM BackendBundle:Video v ORDER BY v.id DESC";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    }
    $page = $request->query->getInt("page", 1);
    $paginator = $this->get("knp_paginator");
    $items_per_page = 6;
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, $items_per_page);

    $total_items_count = $pagination->getTotalItemCount();
    $data = array(
        "status" => "success",
        "total_items_count" => $total_items_count,
        "page_actual" => $page,
        "items_per_page" => $items_per_page,
        "total_pages" => ceil($total_items_count/$items_per_page),
        "data" => $pagination
    );
    return $helper->toJson($data);
}
```

The result should be a JSON with 4 videos.. but I get

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "total_items_count": 0,
    "page_actual": 1,
    "items_per_page": 6,
    "total_pages": 0,
    "data": []
}
```

where "data" is an array with the video data

Somebody know what I miss? the dql consult.. it's rigth?

Somebody could tell me what is the mistake? I need a clue.. the dql consult is correct?

Comment: Hello, you can try to select all datas from your video entity, you will probably need them in your template anyway

$dql = "SELECT v FROM BackendBundle:Video v "
                . "WHERE v.title LIKE :search OR "
                . "v.description LIKE :search ORDER BY v.id DESC";

Comment: I try it.. but return an empty array.. is too extrange.. I don't know what is the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use `knp_paginator` service. Try to get items from paginator like this:

```
$data = array(
    "status" => "success",
    "total_items_count" => $total_items_count,
    "page_actual" => $page,
    "items_per_page" => $items_per_page,
    "total_pages" => ceil($total_items_count/$items_per_page),
    "data" => $pagination->getItems()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replay guys!!

So.. I made a mistake while typing.. and I forgot sign $ before the search word..

thats was the probllem

```
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter("search", "%search%"); <-- here
```

Thank you so much!!